# Can't receive message from Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

ReplyingKafkaTemplate from java server to kotlin server I'm trying to receive requests and responses using .

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value("${devsoo.kafka.restapi.topic}")
    private String requestReplyTopic;
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory(){
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES,"*");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "post-server-consumer-group");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"latest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,true);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Object, String> replyKafkaTemplate
            (ProducerFactory<String, Object> pf,
             KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container) {
        ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Object, String> replyingKafkaTemplate = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
        replyingKafkaTemplate.setDefaultReplyTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000));
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);

    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> replyContainer
            (ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf) {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(requestReplyTopic);
        return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate());
        return factory;
    }


}
```

I tried "VALUE_DESERIALIZER CLASS" with both json and String.

```
public Object replyRecord(KafkaResponseDto requestData) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, JsonProcessingException, TimeoutException {

        ProducerRecord<String, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<String, Object>(kafkaRestApiTopic,requestData);
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, kafkaRestApiTopic.getBytes()));
        RequestReplyFuture<String, Object, String> sendAndReceive = replyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
    
        SendResult<String, Object> sendResult = sendAndReceive.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        sendResult.getProducerRecord().headers().forEach(header -> System.out.println(header.key() + ":" + header.value().toString()));
    
        ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = sendAndReceive.get();
        return consumerRecord.value();
    }
```

this kotlin

```kotlin
@KafkaListener(topics = ["\${devsoo.kafka.restapi.topic}"], groupId = "member-server-consumer-group")     @SendTo     fun getMemberRequestDto(message: String): String? {         val getMemberRequestDto: KafkaMemberValidateRequestDto =             objectMapper.readValue(message, KafkaMemberValidateRequestDto::class.java)         val member = memberService.getInstance(getMemberRequestDto)         return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(member.toKafkaResponseDto())     }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsIxO.png)

Producer sent message to Kafka

However, the consumer could not receive this and received "null".

What's the problem?

I tried "VALUE_DESERIALIZER CLASS" with both json and String.

Comment: I solved this problem.
Producing and consumer were designated as the same topic.
Received without null

Answer (score 0):

can you apply this changes to your consumer config :

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES,"*");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "post-server-consumer-group");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,"latest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,true);
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            props,
            new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(Object.class));    }
```

also your Listener should be   :

```
 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory
```

please note that "Object" can be changed to your entity class if you are refering to a specific object.